# Does “end in” include the date?

Tags: meaning, dates, range-inclusion

I have table with head "End in" and values as "week 5", "week 8", etc.

"End in" Week included? or may be different depending on the context?

For example:

[image: example]

Comment: Welcome to ELU. Please edit and clarify what your exact problem is. It's very difficult to answer given the current minimal context.

Comment: To expand on @BiscuitBoy's comment, *end in* is not a standard phrase, so it's difficult to know precisely what it means without some context.

Comment: If a time span "ends in" a specific week, that mean that it ends in some day of that week, not necessarily the first or last.

Comment: @HotLicks has it right-  If it says it ends in Week 1 then, assuming Week 1 is January 4 through 10, then whatever it is is scheduled to end sometime during that period.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the example given, it means that you are to organize one drawer in your house each week *for each of five weeks, starting with the first week and ending with the fifth.*

At the conclusion of the fifth week, you will have organized five drawers in your house.  So yes, the fifth week is included.

It's possible that there is some context in which the "end in" week was excluded, but I can't think of such a context, and I imagine it would be unlikely.